# Filter Table by column value VueJS Array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I wrote this function to filter by status type. It's working but every time I filter the table data rows get disappeared. There're two status ( Active and Completed ) I wrote this code for filter,

```
                    <div class="DropContent">
                        <label class="LabelView">Status</label><br />
                        <select class="dropdown-size form-control" v-model="ins_status" v-on:change="filterData">
                        <option v-for="(option, i) in optionFilter" :value="i">
                            {{ option }}
                        </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                   filterData(evt) {
                     var val = evt.target.value;
                     if(val==0){
                        this.inspections = this.inspections.filter(function(e){return e.status = "Scheduled"});
                     }if(val==1){
                        this.inspections = this.inspections.filter(function(e){return e.status != "Scheduled"});    
                     }
                  },
```

This is the array that load data to table from a for loop,

[image]

Also inside `0: Object` There's another array which contains data like above objects from the screenshot
[image]

So totally there're 3 rows for the table. Before calling filter function, all 3 rows are visible. but when I filter again and again it reduces the no of rows of the table. According to given data if I filter three times no table records are shown in the table. Help me thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to store this.inspections in a local variable and then filter that variable and store the result inside this.inspections.

```
filterData(evt) {
  var val = evt.target.value;
  var inspections = this.inspections; // save inspections in local variable
  if(val==0){
    this.inspections = inspections.filter(function(e){return e.status = "Scheduled"});
  } if(val==1){
    this.inspections = inspections.filter(function(e){return e.status != "Scheduled"});    
  }
}
```

Comment: still the same not working.

Comment: can you create a working Jsfiddle for the same ?

Comment: you were right. I just missed a prop. with a prop your method succeed. Thanks mate!

Comment: no worries mate!, happy to help you @DevinY

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I modified the existing array. So each time I filter it changes. which means it changes the original table data even I assign it to a local variable. So I passed an extra prop to my working component and assigned it to a local variable.